# Multiple transition properties -> remove only one property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm using CSS transitions to animate multiple properties:

```
div {
    transition: margin-left 2s, height 4s;
}
```

I'd like to remove only the `margin-left` part using jQuery.

I could do this but I don't like the style because everytime I add another property to my CSS I'd have to touch this part too:

```
jQuery( ".ph" ).css("transition", "height 4s");
```

Also I don't want jQuery animations because CSS animations perform much better.

**How can I remove only a single property of the CSS transition-property if it contains more than one?**

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is the question?

Comment: @Hedge sorry if this is a different suggestion, but wouldn't having different classes for each transition and adding/removing classes work better?

Comment: As for me, the way is :
1) add/remove different classes with one transition
2) use replace, like $('selector').css('transition').replace('/margin-left[a-z0-9. ]+,/,'')